# ng-show not working on state change for factory function

Tags: angularjs

I want to change text from login to logout once user is successfully logged in thereby changing url from home to dashboard.

```
 $stateProvider.state('home',{url:'/',views:{'':{templateUrl:'./partials/home/home.tpl.html'},'navbar@home' {templateUrl:'./partials/navbar/navbar.tpl.html'},'lsidebar@home':{templateUrl:'./partials/sidebars/lsidebar.tpl.html'},'content@home'{templateUrl:'./partials/content/content.tpl.html'}},authenticate:false })
  .state('dashboard',{url:'/dashboard',views:{'':{templateUrl:'./partials/home/home.tpl.html'},'navbar@dashboard':{templateUrl:'./partials/navbar/navbar.tpl.html'},lsidebar@dashboard':     {templateUrl:'./partials/sidebars/lsidebar.tpl.html'},'content@dashboard':{templateUrl:'./partials/dashboard/dashboard.tpl.html'}},authenticate:true})
```

sample Factory :

```
coreApp.factory('AuthFactory',function($http){

var obj={}; 
var isAuthenticated=false;

obj.login=function(data){
    return $http.post('http://reqres.in/api/login',data);
}
obj.userInfo=function(){
    isAuthenticated=true;
    return {name:'xyz',balance:'10.00'};
}
obj.isAuthenticated=function(){
    return isAuthenticated;
}

return obj; });
```

HTML :

```
  <a ui-sref='login' ng-show='!AuthFactory.isAuthenticated()'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> Sign in</a>
  <a ui-sref='logout' ng-show='AuthFactory.isAuthenticated()'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i>Logout </a>
```

boostrap :

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state','$stateParams','AUTH_EVENTS','AuthFactory',function($rootScope,   $state,   $stateParams,AUTH_EVENTS,AuthFactory){
 $rootScope.$state = $state;
 $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    if(toState.authenticate &&  !AuthFactory.isAuthenticated())
    {
         $state.transitionTo("login");
         event.preventDefault();
    }   


    console.log("AuthFactory"+AuthFactory.isAuthenticated());
  });

  $rootScope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,function(event){
    console.log('You not logged in');
  });}]);
```

Issue is when user gets logged in root scope is updated and prints value of AuthFactory.isAuthenticated() as true and also url is being changed but my text in lsidebar.tpl.html is not changed.

I did a bit googling I found out that $scope.$apply is a way to do it.But I am confused what is the right way for such case or is it ok to use $scope.$apply on factory function.

Comment: have you tried my solution?

Comment: @Dennis yes it works

Comment: why don't you accept it then?

Comment: @Dennis how about now :-)

Comment: much better now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use services in your templates directly. Services are just objects that Angular knows how to inject in dependable functions.

That said, you need to inject the service and define property in the scope of the controller with a link to the service to be able to use it in your templates.

JS

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.myService = myService;
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myController">{{ myService.someGetterFn() }}</div>
```

**Or**

JS

```
app.controller('myController', ['myService', function (myService) {
    this.myService = myService;
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">{{ ctrl.myService.someGetterFn() }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is a little bit confusing when dealing with in-line expressions. Try:

```
ng-show="(!AuthFactory.isAuthenticated())"
```

Also, and in relation to `$apply()`, the way to use it (not always applicable though) is:

```
$scope.$apply( aaa = true );
```

Be aware that this cannot be invoked in all situations (e.g. if invoked while Angular is *digesting* changes, you will get an error message).

Comment: I think problem is not in expression syntax.Its with angular expression not realising that its value is changed.

Comment: If the change of the value takes place within a function **known** to Angular (e.g. declare as `$scope.MyFont = function (...)`, Angular would know. Otherwise, the `$apply()` would be required.

Comment: Actually there is no controller assigned to that template thats why I wanted to do it via factory or services so that I can use them wherever I want as https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: First of all, it would be considered from your side to make our task (walking through your question) easier; in this example, save us from scrolling sidewise in your first piece of code). Second, and s stated, if the change of the variable takes place OUTSIDE Angular's scope, it will not be reflected in your HTML. Try creating a simple function like `$scope.Test = function () {...}` within the page's controller and change the value there. I suspect that testing the value like `ng-show="My_Variable"` will do the job.